# How to change working directory of Python script during execution?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, cd

I am working on a personal project and I have been stuck here.
I want to change the working directory of my program during its execution but it is not working and there is also no error.

```
def google_search(search_term, api, cse, num = 10):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey = api)
    res = service.cse().list(q = search_term, cx = cse).execute()

    #Creating new folder with search term
    if not os.path.exists(search_term):             
        print('Creating project: ' + search_term)
        os.makedirs(search_term)

    return res['items']
    os.chdir("../test 1/%s" %search_term)
```

When I execute the entire script I get no error, the script executes completely but the directory doesn't change to the directory I have just created using the 'search_term'.

If I individually run the command below in ipython shell(using the search_term value), it executes and takes me to the intended directory.

```
os.chdir("../test 1/%s" %search_term)
```

It is working as an individual command when I put in the name of the directory directly but it is not working when I use it in the whole script.

Comment: Did you check current path `os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` before trying to change it?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the path before and after the execution. The directory didn't change. It is still at 'test 1'.

Comment: could you print search_term before os.chdir and see what do you get ?

Comment: Yes! search_term gets printed when I use this function. If I use 
google_search("Microsoft", api, cse)
Microsoft gets printed and a folder named Microsoft gets created.

Comment: Do you expect that execution of program your shell will have different working directory?
Also in presented code `os.chdir` is after `return` statement, so calling `google_search` will not change working directory inside program.

Comment: Amazing! You are correct. This has worked. I have changed the place of return in my function and it worked. Thank you so much Frane. I tried so many things but didn't notice that I made such a fundamental mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `return` statement before `os.chdir`, so that line is not executed.